# matching an unwanted token in Antlr for error reporting

Tags: antlr4

I have a rule like this (oversimplified but just for demo):

```
matches :
        MATCHES
    ;
```

but sometimes I incorrectly use 'matching' instead of 'matches' in my code and I'd like it to blow up with a nice error msg. I've previously reached for this type of construct

```
matches :
        MATCHES
    |
        MATCHING
        {
            err("Wrong keyword, use MATCHES not MATCHING");
        }
    ;
```

but that requires making a lex symbol MATCHING which will interfere with the lexer. I want to match MATCHING without creating any lex symbol at all.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that, by not Having a Lexer Rule for `matching`, the lexer will identify it as something like an `IDENTIFIER` (assuming your grammar has such rule).

With that in mind, one option might be to let the Lexer identify "matching" as an `IDENTIFIER`.  Then you could write this alternate with `IDENTIFIER` and a semantic predicate that requires the `IDENTIFIER` == "matching".  Then, in a listener if you encounter the Context that passed the semantic tic predicate, you can add your own, custom, error message.

something akin to: (untested code, so there my be minor errors)

```
matches :
        MATCHES
    |
        id=IDENTIFER { $id.text == "matching" }?
    ;
```

You can't really have a successful parse without all of the input being recognized and tokenized.  (A failure to tokenize it, will result in an error message.  ANTLR will attempt error recovery by either inserting or ignoring tokens that allow it to proceed (and produce an error).

Another possible approach to accomplish what you want, with the specific error message; you might be able to use a custom ErrorListener and override the error message (but, it can be tricky to identify the context when the error is detected.)

Comment: First up, duh! Second, yay! Works:

`id = pmqident { $id.text == "matching" }? { err("bloop"); }`

Obvious that it has to be an ident, once told. Re. error handling, I'm not doing anything fancy - hit an problem, squeal & die. That's good enough for now. Custom error handling will have to happen sometime but it looks scary. Accepted. Thanks so much!

Comment: A word of warning: what you are going to do is not a good approach (kinda anti-pattern): you want to enhance your parse step with handling for semantic problems. Instead you should separate the too. If a specific value is syntactically not correct then let the parser report it as error via the normal handling. Otherwise do a walk over the produce parse tree to identify wrong values.

Comment: Let me clarify so we can be sure whether I'm making a real and possibly expensive mistake: this is definitely and strictly a syntactic error. The correct word is MATCHES, but it's too easy to use MATCHING instead and I need to tell the user (I get confused and it's my language). So I *think* it's right here, yes?  In contrast elsewhere, checks are done in a post-parse AST walk for semantic errors eg. "The delete clause may contain ALL or WHERE but not both". Makes sense?

Comment: If you’re matching a parse rule to catch a syntax error and then later, in a Listener, for example, use that Context type to generate an error, it’s still a syntax error.   A Syntax error just means you’ve identified an invalid structure (however you identify it).   *IF* you really want to trigger the error during parse, you can add an action to that rule to add your error, but you start getting target language “stuff” in your grammar, so I use a Listener.